# Parse Login users without Facebook details in Data Browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I am using `[PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissions]` to let user log into Facebook in an iOS app. There is no other option for users to log-in. In the completion block I am calling `[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler]`. In the completion block of second call I store the data obtained into the `[PFUser currentUser]` object (like username, email). The data browser in Parse dashboard shows empty data in email and other info received from Facebook for some of the users. I have proper conditional checks to see if the API calls are returning any errors.

This the code. There are many users with no FBID, Email and corrupted Username in Parse databrowser.

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook error" message:@"To use you Facebook account with this app, open Settings > Facebook and make sure this app is turned on." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {                    
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:result[@"id"] forKey:kPFUser_FBID];
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:result[@"name"] forKey:kPFUser_Username];
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:result[@"email"] forKey:kPFUser_Email];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

It looks like the block is not entering the second piece of code(i.e it is getting error from FBRequestConnection method.
Please help!

Comment: The fields are empty or undefined? Is there any users from Facebook who's email was obtained from Facebook or the users who has an email were signed up without Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was the issue here. I was calling

```
[PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissions]
```

with nil permissions and was trying to access email address of the user. Parse was crashing when a null value was being entered in currentUser object.

Just replaced nil with @"email" permission.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you remembering to save the current user after you finish setting the properties? That's an easy thing to forget.

UPDATE:

Add an else block to log any possible `error` returned from the Facebook call.

Also try changing your `saveInBackground` to `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` and check for any errors, if the data isn't showing up in the Parse Data Browser that should always be the first thing you check.

Comment: Yes. I am saving the currentUser. The PFUser object on parse.com databrowser doesn't shows fbid, username, email.